# Lubuntu won't show desktop after booting

Tags: lubuntu, 19.10

I have just installed Lubuntu 19.10 on an old 64-bit PC ([Intel Celeron 1.6 Ghz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/29734/intel-celeron-processor-420-512k-cache-1-60-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html) with 4 GB RAM).  During installation I had trouble booting up the LiveDVD.

First, there was a *snd_hda_intel corb reset timeout* error, followed by halting at *show plymonth boot screen*).

Now, after successfully installing, after booting Lubuntu (after displaying the logo) the screen turns black with a blinky underscore.

I am able to work around it by opening console mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, logging with my username and password, and the starting the desktop environment with `startx`.

How do I fix this error?

I've tried recovery mode fixing packages but it showed it could not connect to the Ubuntu url. I've also checked for drivers but it says no new drivers found.

This is .xsession-errors

```
Xsession: X session started for lourdes at mié abr 15 15:50:38 -03 2020
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/lourdes/.Xauthority
localuser:lourdes being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/lourdes
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=lourdes
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MOTD_SHOWN=pam
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/lourdes
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=lourdes
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting JOURNAL_STREAM=9:24433
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting INVOCATION_ID=5fb2eda17c334ab0b2bb0af1906d3d38
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/lourdes/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/lourdes
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_UY.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_UY.UTF-8
!: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dbus-daemon[971]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.3' (uid=1000 pid=986 comm="/usr/bin/nm-applet " label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[971]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry

(nm-applet:986): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:50:46.559: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
(0x7ffdb1086cd0) Debug: systemd: "CanReboot" = "yes"
(0x7ffdb1086cd0) Debug: systemd: "CanPowerOff" = "yes"
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
```

I've also followed [this steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634) but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/197910 may have a solution for you.

Comment: Recovery mode (root shell) is ~like runlevel 1 where networking services are inactive, but allowing you to make changes to your file system to correct local issues.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: sorry, but that didn't work